# Komodo Edit Function and Require autocompletion

Tags: php, autocomplete, intellisense, komodo, komodoedit

I'm not sure what to call it so I'm calling it hints. I notice that whenever I'm calling a function, and I hover over that line, little popup bubbles appear that show me the first comment in said function definition. Helps keep track of what that function does or the possible parameters.

But that doesn't always happen, just sometimes. I was wondering if there's a preference I could change so it always does.

Also, if I'm writing and I include or require a file, if that file has functions in it, I'd like it to be able to recognize the function I'm calling from that file and display hints. Is there maybe an option to point the editor toward the included file so it can do that?

And finally, it's looking like it won't detect functions/methods with hinting that are inside of a class. Any workarounds?

Thanks, I wonder if I'm missing a shortcut or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was wondering if there's a preference I could change so it always does.

[Code conventions](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.0/editor.html#PHP_AutoComplete), [API catalogs](http://community.activestate.com/xpi/cake-php), [Intellisense settings](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.0/prefs.html#code_intel), or [Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439730/calltips-docstring-while-viewing-function-list) can help.

> Is there maybe an option to point the editor toward the included file so it can do that?

Goto Edit=>Preferences=>Languages, then add the file paths under [PHP](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/4.4/prefs.html#PHP) or the relevant language.

> And finally, it's looking like it won't detect functions/methods with hinting that are inside of a class. Any workarounds?

Use [PHPDoc/JSDoc](http://community.activestate.com/forum-topic/getting-more-your-php-and-javascript-code) to workaround this.