# Komodo Edit - how to add code completion to a my files

Tags: komodo, komodoedit

I am new to Komodo Edit. How can I add IntelliSense to my own files?

For example: myFirst.js that includes auto completion for objects or functions that were defined in mySecond.js?

Also, how can I add auto completion to my CSS file from my HTML file?

Another example: in Visual Studio I put this statement at the beginning of file2.js:

```
 /// <reference path="../js/file1.js" />
```

And then I had IntelliSense for file1.js inside file2.js.

Comment: Your question is kind of misleading. Your problem is that code intelligence is not working?

Comment: yes. what are the steps in order to gain intellisence with my own files ?

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear. Does code intelligence work at all? With some other files that are not yours? With builtin functions? Do you get a combo if you type `window.`?

Comment: inside css file i have intelligence .inside html file i have intelligence for html (but not for my css class that where referenced..) inside javascript file i have intelligence for javascript, but not for jquery that was included in the html file.  I need to know how to include intelligence of one file inside another file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Komodo Edit Function and Require autocompletion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857062/komodo-edit-function-and-require-autocompletion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open menu *Edit* → *Preferences* → *Languages* → *JavaScript* and specify directory with your source files.

Komodo will scan them for information about your functions.

Comment: I did that and got it to autocomplete for my own variables. But it doesn't show my variable in the *list*.

Answer (score 1):

As long as both files are under the same project, Komodo should automatically pick up on them and provide code intelligence. But make sure you are using a *project* and not just editing your files plainly as Komodo will not know how to associate your files.

Note though that if you are abstracting your JavaScript code too much that code intelligence will not be able to keep track of what you are trying to do. But you'd have to include some samples of your code for us to be able to comment further on that.

Also note this open bug, which may be related to your issue: http://bugs.activestate.com/show_bug.cgi?id=101646

Comment: The link is broken (Firefox says *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at bugs.activestate.com."*).